# argparse displays __main__.py instead of executable module name

Tags: python

When using `argparse` in an executable module, the help message displays `__main__.py` instead of the module name. How to correct this?

```
$python -m mymodule -h

usage: __main__.py [-h]`

My executable python module

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instruction `python -m mymodule` runs the `__main__.py` script located in `mymodule`, this is why argparse uses `__main__.py` as program name ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog)).

The program name can be overridden with the `prog` argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='python -m mymodule',
        description='My executable python module.')
```

indeed:

```
$python -m mymodule -h

usage: python -m mymodule [-h]

My executable python module

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```